# VBA-Excel Is it possible to use PivotFilters.Add to manage multiple filter values on a PivotField of a PivotTable. In my case, I always get error#5

Tags: excel, vba

When using this code Error #5 on the last statement:

```
Sub ApplyFilter()
    Dim PVF As PivotField
    Set PVF = ActiveCell.PivotField
    PVF.ClearAllFilters
    PVF.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlFilterValues, Value1:="MGT-D-EC-AFFP"
End Sub
```

However "MGT-D-EC-AFFP" does exist in the list values of that field !!
And the ClearAllFilters works fine

Who can help ?

An other way for applying multiple filter values exists, but it supposes to loop through all the values of that field, and set them visible true or false.
And in my case, it takes too long time, even with ManualUpdate set to true

Thank you for help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpivotfiltertype   `xlFilterValues` doesn't appear in that list?